# Filtering by a navigation property (string filter) in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core and I'm having a problem with a query that uses a *Navigation Property*. `Product` is the entity, and `Provider` is the related entity.

The example is pretty easy to understand.

```
var query = _context.Products
                .Include(p => p.Provider)
                .Where(p => ValidationExtensions.ValidatesFilter("something", p.Name));
```

Where ValidatesFilter is an Extension Method:

```
internal static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static bool ValidatesFilter(this string str, string referenceStr)
    {
        if (str == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (referenceStr == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || ValidateStr(str, referenceStr);
    }

    private static bool ValidateStr(string str, string referenceStr)
    {
        if (str.StartsWith("*"))
        {
            return referenceStr.EndsWith(AsString(str.Skip(1)), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        if (str.EndsWith("*"))
        {
            return referenceStr.StartsWith(AsString(str.TakeWhile(c => c != '*')), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        if (str.Contains('*'))
        {
            bool containsAllChunks;
            var chunksToCheck = str.Split(new[] { "*" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            containsAllChunks = chunksToCheck.All(s => referenceStr.Contains(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            return containsAllChunks;
        }

        return string.Equals(str, referenceStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private static string AsString(this IEnumerable<char> characters)
    {
        return string.Concat(characters);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to filter using the navigation property, so I'm using Include, but when running the code, `p.Provider` is `null`, so it fails. It seems that `Include` isn't loading the navigation property.

How is this done, then?

Comment: `Include` is not needed in order to use navigation property in L2E query as soon as the expression is translatable to SQL. What EFC version are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that every product has an assigned provider? And does every provider have a name?

Comment: @IvanStoev You're right. The problem is that my query isn't translatable to L2E. I will update the OP with the method I'm actually using.

Comment: @IvanStoev Updated! You don't have to check the whole Extension Method, but it's a bit complex. It uses StarsWith, Contains, EndsWidth and a bit something more. Is that the problem?

Comment: Indeed. There is no way to translate custom method to SQL, so it does client evaluation. And I think at the time it's doing it the `Include` is not yet processed. Most likely a bug. But it would be always better if you can replace the method with translatable expression.

Comment: One thing i see is `TakeWhile` cannot be translated as SQL, but `StartWith` , `endsWith` and `contains` will work

Comment: Also forget about putting `ValidatesFilter` inside a EF `where` clause